# Will using kml file to plot details in google maps hit google api usage limit?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to draw a region near my area  in Google Maps from points in kml file.  I am using large number of points for plotting my area. Will it affect in anyway since Google limits using of their maps 2500 request per day. Is this usage limit is applicable for native Maps APIs for Android mobile platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no usage limit for Google Maps Android API v2.